# Show that $e^x > \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, induction

Knowing that $e^x > 1+x$, I'm supposed to use induction to prove that $ e^x > \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}$ when $x > 0$.

The basic step is fairly simple, for $n=1$ the sum equals to $1+x$, and we have proven that.

I then assume it holds for $n = k$, and have:
$$ e^x > \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

and therefor for $n = k+1$, I have:
$$ e^x > \sum_{n=0}^k x^n/n! + \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

The problem is I have no idea how I go forward. How do I use it to prove it?

Comment: What definition for $e$ or $e^x$ are you starting with? The answer will depend on your definition. For instance, if you define $e^x = \sum_0^\infty x^n/n!$ then this is almost obvious. But if you start with $e^x = \lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + x/n)^n$ then it takes more work to show this.

Comment: Also have a look at this Kconrad notes (theorem 4.4 Page 7)(https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/proofs/induction.pdf). This pdf has two proofs of your result (for inductive step): one is by differentiation and other is by integration